# Sending image in android sends as .dat and not .png

Tags: android, android-intent, png

I'm using an intent to send an image and it works just fine but for some reason it sends as a .dat file and not a .png file. Here is the code that is used to send the image

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");      
localIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.t4t.stickerwhatsapp/" + videoDetails.get(pos)));
localIntent.setType("image/png"); 
startActivityForResult(localIntent,111);
```

Anyone have any ideas on why it's being sent as a .dat?

I also tried setting the setType to image/jpg and stil sends a .dat.

Comment: What kind of data does the videoDetails.get(pos)) return?

Comment: That returns an id to the image that is located inside the drawable directory. It's pretty much the same as R.drawable.icon_to_use

Comment: But shouldn't your uri contain 'drawable' ? android.resource://com.t4t.stickerwhatsapp/<--- drawable /

Comment: I just added the drawable and it's behaving the same way. I get the file as a .dat and when I remname it to .png it works fine. What's even stranger I just noticed is my old test device sends it as a png and my galaxy s3 sends it as a .dat. Not sure if it's OS related or device related. Will have to try other test devices.

Comment: That's really weird, too bad I couldn't help :(